# Highmaps scroll down when page load - Angular SPA

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, single-page-application, highmaps

I m developing report page. In this page I m using highcharts and highmaps together. At first load there is no more problem but when user click the another page, then back to again this report page highmaps area scroll down.

I have single page application, so every link using ajax call.

I found this solution, but this way I cannot store any rootscope element. Also I dont want to use cookies or localstorage.

```
$('#mapsmaps').highcharts('Map', {
        title : {
            text : 'City Lived',  
            style: {
            color: '#008bff'
            }
        },

        subtitle : {
            text : ''
        },        
        legend: {
            title: {
                text: ' ',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'black'
                }
            },
            floating: true,
            valueDecimals: 0,
            valueSuffix: '',
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85)',
            symbolRadius: 0,
            symbolHeight: 10,

           },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: false,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
           // backgroundColor: 'none',
            // borderWidth: 0,
            // shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            padding: 0,
            pointFormat: '<span class="f32"></span>'
                + ' {point.name}'
        },
        colorAxis: { 
            dataClasses: [{
                from: 1,
                to: 1000,
                color: "#5FA08F"
            }, {
                from: 1000,
                to: 2000,
                color: "#82A970"
            }, {
                from: 2000,
                to: 3000,
                color: "#E5AF47"
            }, {
                from: 3000,
                to: 4000,
                color: "#EC8A37"
            }, {
                from: 4000,
                to: 5000,
                color: "#F55126"
            }, {
                from: 5000,
                color: "#F30505"
            }]
        },

        series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/en/en-all'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            name: 'City',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: '#BADA55'
                }
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }

        }],
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Hard to tell you the problem without any code.

Comment: I add it my highcharts code. When I open this page from another page with ajax, the maps working wrong. Its scrolling bottom of the page. Also exceeds container div.

Comment: Could you replicate your issue as live demo, because this code seems to working fine, without problems.

Comment: Are you sure is it related to Highcharts/maps or, is it because of you are navigation away and back to a long page?

What do you mean by navigation? Leaving to page completely or changing some kind of a state, a spa-like navigation using `ng-router` or something like that?